# Where can I get the SourceToken for the customer creation in Stripe?

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments, token, payment

Where can I get the SourceToken for the customer creation in Stripe?

Here is the example of the code which uses the `SourceToken`:

```
if (Request.Form["stripeToken"] != null) {
    var customers = new CustomerService();
    var charges = new ChargeService();

    var customer = customers.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions {
        Email = Request.Form["stripeEmail"],
        SourceToken = Request.Form["stripeToken"]
    });

    var charge = charges.Create(new ChargeCreateOptions {
        Amount = 500,
        Description = "Sample Charge",
        Currency = "usd",
        CustomerId = customer.Id
    });

    Console.WriteLine(charge);
}
```

What is `SourceToken` out of this `json`?

```
{
  "id": "tok_1EL43MKfPgrABB02rh7IGG7l",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_1EL43MKfPgrABB02yFgReMXc",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "cvc_check": "pass",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 12,
    "exp_year": 2020,
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {},
    "name": "foo@gmail.com",
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "client_ip": "194.44.142.6",
  "created": 1554278556,
  "email": "foo@gmail.com",
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

Here is how I got the json:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_ob6s7KZxZU1mouJbbsuFBjEe');

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_ob6s7KZxZU1mouJbbsuFBjEe',
    token: function(token, args) {
        var stop = 0;
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets ($20.00)',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

on line `var stop = 0;`.

The example is taken from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/webforms#step-1-create-project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SourceToken in that JSON is `"tok_1EL43MKfPgrABB02rh7IGG7l"`.

After the customer is created with the source attached (e.g. that token), you can [retrieve the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve?lang=dotnet) which will include that customer's sources (they'll be listed in the `sources` object under the `customer` record).

The token itself gets consumed during the creation of the source and customer, and the result is a source that's reusable.

Comment: `After the customer is created` Who should create the customer? Thank you.

Comment: The customer will be created, in the example, on the call to `var customer = customers.Create( ... )`. The submitted form would contain the two parameters that are passed to that call.

Comment: How can I get the `SourceToken` on frontend? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure at what point you're looking for it. Could you clarify? It should be entered on the form from the example. That form is then submitted to your backend and the code you showed is called.

Comment: I updated my question. Could you, please, check it out? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I've updated my answer to include specifying what is the actual token in the JSON you're seeing.

Comment: Great! Thank you.